# Coordinator-AppBar-Toolbar Layout Scroll Behaviour with ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments

I recorded my screen:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=js4EZlY706A

You can see that you have to make an "extra scroll" if you are at the top of the recyclerview. I am using a ViewPager and Fragment and within the Fragment is a recyclerview. Here is some code:

Activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">


            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlwaysCollapsed"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />


            <com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                app:pstsPaddingMiddle="true" />


        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

And the recyclerview of the fragment is just:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

So the question is how can I prevent the "extra scroll" and show the toolbar immediately after the recyclerview is at the top?